# Displaying users who fit multiple roles discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am designing a bot using discord.js version 12. I am trying to make it send a private message to the author showing which users in the server have the user inputted roles. The function `roledisplayCommand` will require the user to type `role` then the different roles they want to search. It is able to display all users with a specific role but adding more than 1 role seems to confuse it. For example, if Spookybot and SpookySeed both have the `member` role but only SpookySeed has the `admin` role, if the user types `role member admin` I want it to ONLY display SpookySeed as he has both roles. How can I accomplish this?

```
function roleDisplayCommand(arguments, receivedMessage) {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        const roleNames = receivedMessage.content.split(" ").slice(1);

        receivedMessage.author.send(`These users have the ${roleNames.join(" ")} role(s)` )
        
        let users = receivedMessage.guild.members.cache;
        const userList = roleNames.every(
          role => {
            users = users.filter(u => u.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === role))
          })
          receivedMessage.author.send(Array.from(userList.values()).join("\n"));
        
    }
     else {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("Unknown command")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be putting the `every()` function in the `filter()` function, not the other way around.

```js
const users = receivedMessage.guild.members.cache;
const userList = users.filter((user) =>
 roleNames.every((name) => user.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === name))
);
```

This will filter the collection down to users that have roles corresponding to every name in the array.

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how excited this makes me. I tired out your code and it works thannk you!

Comment: Glad I could help! Be sure to mark my answer as accepted if it answered your question so that it's easier to find for others in the future that have the same problem.